# Can't get Facebook log-in screen?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the [Facebook Android SDK tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#build) and I have all of the code leading up to this step in my app. I start the app (testing it on my phone, but does the same in Emulator) and this screen comes up:

[image]

Ok, great!

But, once it's done loading, instead of any sort of log-in screen coming up like the example given here:

[image]

I just come up with this:

[image]

Code:

```
package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MY_APP_ID");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**Ok, I deleted the project and started again. This screen from before is doing something, but keeps reloading this loading screen over and over and over again. Almost like it's contacting Facebook's servers for 1000 different things and each one has a loading screen. I don't know what to do. No errors in Logcat.**

[image]

Comment: Do you have native fb app installed on phone?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Is there any error message in logcat?
Do you use Internet permission?
Check these things.

or maybe you have already completed

or add some log in your code for example:

```
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d("onComplete",""+values);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.d("onFacebookError",""+error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.d("onError",""+e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("onCancel","cancel");
        }
    });
```

and see result in your logcat

Comment: INTERNET is added. No errors in LogCat. After adding that code, I don't get ANYTHING in the Logcat. No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code like this:

```
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {
public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"email", "publish_checkins", "publish_stream","offline_access"}; 
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MY_APP_ID");


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this,PERMISSIONS,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH ---> will login facebook forcefully

also you need to call **facebook.logout(context)** method to logout current method ,before login with new user.

User this method:

```
public void Logout() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        facebook.logout(mContext);
    }
```